# Hibernate set last_updated column to current_timestamp with every update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Following the in-database example in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/topical/html_single/generated/GeneratedValues.html#__valuegenerationtype_meta_annotation, I am able to get hibernate to produce insert statements that look like

```
insert into my_table (col_1, col_2,..., col_n, last_updated) values (?, ?,... current_timestamp)
```

However, I also want it to produce update statements that look like

```
update my_table set col_1=?, col_2=?,..., col_n=?, last_updated = current_timestamp where ...
```

but instead I seem to just be getting

```
update my_table set col_1=?, col_2=?,..., col_n=? where ...
```

Here's a snippet of Java code I'm using:

```
public class MyEntity {
...
    @LastUpdatedColumn
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    Instant last_updated;

    @ValueGenerationType(generatedBy = LastUpdatedGeneration.class)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface LastUpdatedColumn{
    }

    public static class LastUpdatedGeneration implements
        AnnotationValueGeneration<LastUpdatedColumn> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(LastUpdatedColumn annotation, Class<?> propertyType) {
        }

        @Override
        public GenerationTiming getGenerationTiming() {
            return GenerationTiming.ALWAYS;
        }

        @Override
        public ValueGenerator<?> getValueGenerator() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean referenceColumnInSql() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDatabaseGeneratedReferencedColumnValue() {
            return "current_timestamp";
        }
    }
...
```

and elsewhere I use Spring Boot/Spring JPA to just do:

```
myRepository.saveAll(setOfMyEntities)
```

My main requirement here is to use the insert time from the database (rather than from the application server), but I'd also like to avoid having to use database triggers (though Postgres triggers would be acceptable).

Comment: Postgres triggers would be acceptable but no database triggers???

Comment: Acceptable but not ideal

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate 5.2 and above you can do this:

```
@Version
@Column(name = "last_updated")
Instant lastUpdated;
```

This has the additional benefit of rolling back a transaction if the row has been updated by another thread.

IDEs and validators might tell you that this is an invalid type to use the `@Version` annotation on, because this is a Hibernate-specific support, and not part of JPA 2.2 or below.

Comment: This seems to be just giving me primary key constraint violation errors.

Comment: This will also use the Server time and not the database time

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you can see in the following test: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6c5e1726093a5347551b61d9e84ae9dd9f08ece6/documentation/src/test/java/org/hibernate/userguide/mapping/generated/DatabaseValueGenerationTest.java

Try reproducing the issue with plain Hibernate and the latest Hibernate version. Maybe it's a bug or a problem with Spring Data JPA that you are facing.